# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Trying to do the following:

```
order.ExpirationDate =(DateTime) ( ExpMonth + "/" + ExpYear);
```

ExpMonth, Expyear are both ints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is going to be better for you:

```
order.ExpirationDate = new DateTime(ExpYear, ExpMonth, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
DateTime.Parse(ExpMonth.ToString() + "/" + ExpYear.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(ExpMonth + "/" + ExpYear, out dt))
{
   // success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new DateTime using the constructor which takes month and year as parameters (it also takes a day, but you can default to 1) instead of casting a string, it's much cleaner and easier.